# Does H61H2-M12 has trusted platform module?

Tags: motherboard

I check and cannot see that.

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813135288

No trusted platform module mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With questions like these, it's a good idea to find the motherboard's service manual.  This is usually produced by the manufacturer and includes detailed specs and installation instructions.

Typically a simple search, e.g., "H61H2-M12 Service Manual" will bring it up, though sometimes you need to look through the manufacturer website.

After reviewing the manufacturer provided manual at http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?DetailID=1289&CategoryID=1&MenuID=103&LanID=0#fragment-Download, I don't see any mention of TPM.  This board does not have one.